# Getting 404 after oauth2 authentication success and an anonymous token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am using oauth2 with **springboot 1.5.6.RELEASE** and I am using jdbc authentication with oauth2.

I added the property: `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3`

**1- AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    @Lazy
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        // endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

**2- ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter**

```
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/ws/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

**3- SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registerCompany", "/registerEmployee", "/jobs", "/returnPassword", "/resetPassword",
                        "/faces/public/**", "/resources/**", "/template/**", "/faces/fonts/*",
                        "/faces/javax.faces.resource/**", "/ws/**", "/login", "/oauth/**", "/error")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**", "/faces/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/employeeProfile", "/employeeMainPage", "/employeeAskJob").hasAuthority("ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
                .antMatchers("/companyProfile", "/companyMainPage", "/companyPostJob", "/companySearch",
                        "/branchProfile")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_COMPANY,ROLE_BRANCH,ROLE_ADMIN").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(successHandler).failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").and().logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().rememberMe();
        // http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalidSession");

        // cache resources
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/javax.faces.resource/**"), new HeaderWriter() {

                    @Override
                    public void writeHeaders(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
                        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=86400");
                    }
                })).defaultsDisabled();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

}
```

I am trying to generate a token using postman with a post request to url `http://localhost:8082/dawam2/oauth/token?grant_type=password` 
and I use **basic authentication** and set the **username=myclient_id** and **password=myclient_secret**. So the **header (Authorization : Basic Basic bXljbGllbnRfaWQ6bXljbGllbnRfc2VjcmV0)** was generated
and I set the header **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8**.

The response I am getting instead of a generated token :

```
!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Not Found</p><p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M18</h3></body></html>
```

Here are the debugging info:

```
     2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - matched
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1d47c7a
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,833 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /oauth/token' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'myclient_id'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,834 DEBUG o.s.s.a.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2017-09-26 15:32:16,849 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d9cf8114: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@6a9879e3: Username: myclient_id; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_EMPLOYEE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_EMPLOYEE
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d9cf8114: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@6a9879e3: Username: myclient_id; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_EMPLOYEE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_EMPLOYEE'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy - Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@15d6aaa
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?grant_type=password; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,850 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d9cf8114: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@6a9879e3: Username: myclient_id; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_EMPLOYEE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_EMPLOYEE
2017-09-26 15:32:16,851 DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@14cb584, returned: 1
2017-09-26 15:32:16,851 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
2017-09-26 15:32:16,851 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2017-09-26 15:32:16,851 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token?grant_type=password reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-09-26 15:32:16,853 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
2017-09-26 15:32:16,853 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,854 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /login
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-09-26 15:32:16,855 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error?grant_type=password reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-09-26 15:32:16,856 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2017-09-26 15:32:16,856 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
2017-09-26 15:32:16,856 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You didn't really describe what you did to try and obtain a token (the URL you  pasted doesn't match the one in the logs, and you didn't show the headers), and you didn't finish explaining what went wrong. It looks to me like a successful authentication in the logs, but there is no way to identify the user from the URL, so I'd be surprised if there was a token generated.

Comment: @Dave Syer, sorry for not being clear enough, i added the full request url and headers and current behavior and expected behavior.

Comment: So you have a user and a client with the same id and password? That's a bit strange. BTW you don't need the client credentials in the query string. Other than that I can't see anything obvious. But the response is a 404, so the chances are you just didn't register the token endpoint, or the URL path is wrong.

Comment: @Dave Syer how to register token end point ? and what url path do you mean ?

Comment: Normally you only need to `@EnableAuthorizationServer`. The URL path you used is `/dawam/oauth2/token`. There's no way to verify if that is correct without a complete runnable sample.

Comment: @Dave Syer, i also added: 
`security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=http://localhost:8082/dawam/oauth/check_token
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=true
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8082/dawam/userInfo`

with no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155299/discussion-between-mahmoud-saleh-and-dave-syer).

Comment: @Dave Syer, project is uploaded to both svn and github 
https://github.com/devmsaleh/dawam2
https://svn.riouxsvn.com/dawam2/
but preferably run it on tomcat 9 as war

Comment: @@Dave Syer, i figured out the issue, and i uploaded a working example to  https://github.com/devmsaleh/dawam3
the issue is related to jersey, when i disable jersey everything works fine and i get a generated token, but actually i need oauth2 to work with jersey, how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to **Jersey configuration**, it was stealing requests from oauth2, i had to reconfigure it with `@ApplicationPath("/ws")`
so the configuration now looks like :

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/ws")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(DawamService.class);
    }
}
```

and my webservice implementation class like :

```
@Component
@Path("/dawam")
public class DawamService extends DawamServiceBase {

       @GET
       @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML })
       @Path("/test")
       public String getHTML() {
         System.out.println("##### Welcome to test webservice #########");
         return "Welcome to test webservice";
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I can fixed it.
In my case the reason was in the following:

1. My servlet-mapping for dispather servlet in web.xml

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

   It means the all http requests for access to your resources should be started with '/api' (ex. */api/user/2 or /api/login*) even if @RequestMapping points as '*/user/{id}*' or */login*. When you request a token by *oauth2/token* URL, spring or other filters handle it, but dispatcherServlet could not find any controller corresponding to your request and we have 404 error.

To resolve this, I just added the one method to endpoints in AuthorizationServerConfiguration class.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
      ...
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .prefix("/api") //<---- PREFIX WAS ADDED
                    .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
       }
    ...
    }
```

I think the

```
       .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/oauth/token")
```

code instead of `.prefix("/api")` also can resolve the problem.
It changes request for getting the tokens.

After made change I get the tokens by URL
`/api/oauth/token`

Of course I can mistake but it works for me. Thanks.